How to correctly encode special characters in URL parameters with `requests.get()` in Python?
I want to grab some content from a website using requests.get() on jupyter notebook, with a Python version of 3.10.
The website is a simple search engine with a search bar and some buttons.
When I type apple, the browser leads to a URL ending with ?search=apple. When I type α, the browser leads to a URL ending with ?search=%u03B1.
I tried to grab the content using the following code:
import requests

def search(keyword):
    url = "xxxxxxxxxxx.asp"
    params = { 'search': key }
    headers = { ... }
    res = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    return res.content

search('α')

However, this did not return the results for "α". Instead, it returned search results for a Traditional Chinese character 帢.
I then tried this,
search("%u03B1")

but it returned the results for "%u03B1" instead of "α".
How can I solve this?
(What I've tried)



input (params)
url (what I actually got)
search results (res.content)




α
?search=%CE%B1
contents that contain 帢


β
?search=%CE%B2
contents that contain 帣


γ
?search=%CE%B3
contents that contain 帠


%u03B1
?search=%25u03B1
contents that contain %u03B1


%u03B2
?search=%25u03B2
contents that contain %u03B2


%u03B3
?search=%25u03B3
contents that contain %u03B3


...
...
...



(What I expected to be like)



inputs (using website's searching bar)
url (what I saw on the browser)
search results (browser)




α
?search=%u03B1
contents that contain α


β
?search=%u03B2
contents that contain β


γ
?search=%u03B3
contents that contain γ


...
...
...




I guess that the website behind xxx.asp must also decode your search string in the same way, if this is not the case you're lost, related https://stackoverflow.com/a/2744184/2176756

Looks like the server side doesn't know how to decode a properly encoded URL. The substitution sequence of %CE%B1 is entirely correct. That sequence should not be interpreted as \uCEB1

@jhole @SIGHUP, I discovered that I can't get the results I want because the params need to be encoded in a format similar to Unicode, like %u03B1 (Unicode: U+03B1). However, params in requests uses percent-encoding.
For example, if I input α, it requests %CE%B1.
If I input %u03B1, it requests %25u03B1 (% is encoded as %25).
But what I actually need is %u03B1.

I am wondering if it is possible to request a URL with params that skip the percent-encoding.

Wouldn't the first step to be to determine what formats are expected by the API. There seems to be a mismatch between what their API does and what you expect it to do.

The API is using an internal schema rather than Webstandards. A URL appended by ?search=%u03B1 is not standards compliant. The % is used as the start of an escaped two digit digit hexadecimal representation of a byte. Whereas the the site you are using has an internal representation for unicode characters escaping them by codepoints instead of utf-8 bytes. requests if you try to use url as is requests will sanatise it. I'm not sure of you can flag % as a safe character.

You might need to manually construct the search keyword with ord(). ord() returns the Unicode code point of a character.
For example,
def search(keyword): 
    url = "<your_url>" 
    encoded_keyword = '%u{:04X}'.format(ord(keyword)) 
    params = {'search': encoded_keyword} 
    headers = <your_headers> 
    res = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers) 
    print(res.url) # %25u03B1 
    return res.content 

print(search('α')) 

Hope this will work.

Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work as expected.  I found out that I can't get the results I want because the params need to be encoded as something similar to Unicode, like %u03B1 (Unicode: U+03B1), instead of %25u03B1 (since the % in the params would be auto-encoded as %25%).


did not return the results for "α". Instead, it returned search
results for a Traditional Chinese character 帢.

This is sign that search page uses different encoding than python-requests, which assumes utf-8.
α   ?search=%u03B1
β   ?search=%u03B2
γ   ?search=%u03B3

Used above hints I investigated various encodings known to python and it seems to be some variant of utf_16_be considering that
import binascii
entities = ["α","β","γ"]
for entity in entities:
    print(entity, binascii.hexlify(entity.encode("utf_16_be")))

gives output
α b'03b1'
β b'03b2'
γ b'03b3'

Observe direct correspondence of values (hex digits are case-insensitive i.e. 03b1 is equal to 03B1)

I found out that the params need to be encoded in a format similar to Unicode to performed as I expected, like %u03B1 (Unicode: U+03B1). However, params in requests are percent-encoded. For example, if I input α, it outputs %CE%B1. If I input %u03B1, it outputs %25u03B1. But what I actually need is %u03B1."

I am wondering if it is possible to request a URL with params that skip the percent-encoding.

@WarrenChen whilst it is good practice to use params, in your case you might ignore it and prepare url already with querystring part, that is doing something like requests.get("http://www.somesearchengine.asp/?search=%u03B1", headers=headers)
