# International Domain Names

Tags: php, http, web, subdomain

When I navigate to `aртем.example.com`, the web browser will convert the URL to `xn--a-jtbvok.example.com`. Is there a way to convert `xn--a-jtbvok` back to `aртем` using PHP?

Currently I am using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to fetch the requested URL.

Live examples here: [aртем.lekintepls.se](http://a%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC.lekintepls.se) and [åäö.lekintepls.se](http://%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6.lekintepls.se).

I have no idea what this phenomena is called, so I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: I would recommend using only *standard* characters in URLs, but why don't you just check if it equals `xn--a-jtbvok`? `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'xn--a-jtbvok') { /* ... */ }`

Comment: I want the subdomain to be displayed on the page, just like it is now. It's literally the site's only purpose. Making checks for every possible subdomain isn't possible.

Comment: As said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1916747/4255615), URLs should only contain the *standard* characters available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is called Punycode or IDNA (Internationalizing Domain Names in Applications).

You can use the [idn_to_utf8](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-utf8.php) and [idn_to_ascii](http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php) to convert between to two notations.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916747/4255615), the [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) says that:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

This suggests that unicode characters should not be used in URLs.